# Does a turbojet aircraft restriction on a SID or STAR also apply to turbofan aircraft?

Tags: sid-star

Just wondering since I've never seen turbofan aircraft mentioned on SID or STAR charts, and many airliners are turbofan nowadays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term "turbojet" in this context is used a bit more loosely. The [pilot-controller glossary document](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg_4-03-14.pdf) from the FAA defines it as follows:

> TURBOJET AIRCRAFT− An aircraft having a jet engine in which the energy
>   of the jet operates a turbine which in turn operates the air
>   compressor.

You can see this is general enough to include turbofan aircraft as well. The main distinction is vs. a turboprop, where the turbine drives the propeller.